# Use attribute from Optional[Union[str, int]] parameter depending on its type

Tags: python, attributes, union, option-type, mypy

I have a parameter of type: `a: Optional[Union[str, int]]`.

I want to use some attributes when it is a string and other ones when it's an integer.
Eg:

```
    if type(a) is int:
        self.a = a
    elif type(a) is str and a.endswith('some prefix'):
        self.b = a
```

However, MyPy complains with the following:

> error: Item "int" of "Union[str, int, None]" has no attribute "endswith"
>
> error: Item "None" of "Union[str, int, None]" has no attribute "endswith"

Is there a way to make this work with MyPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom you should be using is `isinstance(a, int)` instead of `type(a) is int`. If you do the former and write:

```
if isinstance(a, int):
    self.a = a
elif isinstance(a, str) and a.endswith('some_prefix'):
    self.b = a
```

...then your code should type-check cleanly.

The reason why doing `type(a) is int` isn't supported/most likely won't be supported any time soon is because what you're basically asserting there is that 'a' is *exactly* an int and no other type.

But we actually don't have a clean way of writing such a type in PEP 484 -- if you say some variable 'foo' is of type 'Bar', what you're really saying is that 'foo' could be of type 'Bar' *or* any subclass of 'Bar'.

Comment: Surely it shouldn't be necessary to be able to express the exact-ness of a type when supporting `type(x) is X` as typeguard? Mypy could still conclude the same thing as in the case of `isinstance`.